# Why is my code failing to return data with parameters

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I'm a begginer im doing login form using vb with MySql but i've faced a problem whenever I press Login the system brings me back to the code pointing at adapter.Fill(table) with a dialogue:Exception User-Unhandled and insdide it says: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'Renci.SshNet, Version=2016.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=1cee9f8bde3db106'. The system cannot find the file specified.'
this is my code

Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient

Public Class functions
Dim db As New db()

```
'a function to return table data
Function getDataWithoutParams(ByVal query As String) As DataTable

    Dim command As New MySqlCommand(query, db.getConnection())

    Dim adapter As New MySqlDataAdapter(command)

    Dim table As New DataTable()

    adapter.Fill(table)

    Return table

End Function

'function to return data table with parameters
Function getDataWithParams(ByVal command As MySqlCommand) As DataTable

    Dim adapter As New MySqlDataAdapter(command)

    Dim table As New DataTable()

    adapter.Fill(table)

    Return table

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Good idea to separate your database code from your user interface code but it looks like you are creating database object outside of the method where they are used. This can cause problems because these objects need to be disposed. `Using` blocks handle closing and disposing.

Code for a login form might look like this. I had to guess at the name of the table and fields. Since you only need a single piece of data you can use `ExecuteScalar`.

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    If ValidateUser(txtUserName.Text, txtPassword.Text) Then
        'User is valid
    Else
        'User is not valid
    End If
End Sub

Private OPConStr As String = "Your connection string."

Function ValidateUser(ByVal UserName As String, Password As String) As Boolean
    Dim Count As Integer
    Using cn As New MySqlConnection(OPConStr),
            cmd As New MySqlCommand("Select Count(*) From `Users` Where `UserName` = @userName And `password` = @Password;", cn)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@UserName", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = UserName
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Password", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Password
        cn.Open()
        Count = CInt(cmd.ExecuteScalar)
    End Using
    If Count = 1 Then
        Return True
    End If
    Return False
End Function
```